# Different name in Passport and Residence Permit

Tags: air-travel, india, denmark

I recently corrected the name and surname in my (Indian) passport while renewing it. Is there’s any issue in travelling with my work residence permit (Schengen country) which has the old name? I have all necessary documents.

Comment: Then go, with your new passport, to the immigration office that issued the residence permit and inform them of the name change.

Comment: The problem is I am in India at the moment and the office that issued my permit is in Copenhagen. I would like to get back there, but I wonder if it’s an issue.

Comment: Then add that information to your question. Include whether you still have the canceled old passport, which you should take with you when returning to show immigration control if required.

Comment: I am not able to edit it right away but thank you for your comment.